# How to include .'\1' in replace pattern in regular expression preg_replace command in php

Tags: php, regex

How to include .'\1' in replace pattern in regular expression preg_replace command in php.
My Code :

```
$input = $_GET['post'];
$str = $input;
$pattern = "(.+)";
$output = preg_replace($pattern, ".'\1'", $str);
echo $output;
```

Thanks

Test Input , Output required is :
Input :

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Output :

```
.'line1'
.'line2'
.'line3'
```

another example :
Input :

```
line1

line3
```

output :

```
.'line1'

.'line3'
```

Sample 1 Input , Output: Input string : `test` output string: `.'test'`

Comment: Please add sample input and output for your question.

Comment: Sample 1 Input , Output:
Input string :
`test`
output string:
`.'test'`

Comment: Sample 2 Input , Output:
Input string :
`line1`
`line2`
output string:
`.'line1'`
`.'line2'`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, edit your question instead of adding test data in the comments.

Comment: how we can convert .'\1' to string to include double qoutation marks : ".'\1'" in preg_replace command in php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think preg function cost a lot for such easy task. You better use concatenation.

```
$str = ".".$str;
```

But if you want:

```
$str = "test";
$pattern = "/(.+)/";
$output = preg_replace($pattern, '.$1', $str);
echo $output;
```

**UPD:**

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = <<<HERE
line1
line2 line3


line4
HERE;

$output = preg_replace("/^(.*?)\r?\n?$/m", ".'$1'", $str);

echo $output;
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d121c03df4f6de49595870dff4adc1eea526c97)

**UPD2:**

```
<?php
$str = <<<HERE
line1
line2 line3


line4
HERE;

$output = preg_replace("/^(?!\s)(.*?)\r?\n?$/m", ".'$1'", $str);

echo $output;
```

**[DEMO](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/214f9bff92108b729cd6dad4e44b9414ad3bac93)**

Comment: I need to add .' to the first of each line of my input string and ' to the end of each line of my input string

Comment: thanks for the reply , I tested your code, it does not work as I need :
sample input and output that it produce :
sample input :
`line1`
`line2`
`line3`
output that your code produce :
`.'line'`
`.line'`
`.'line'`
but output that we need is :
`.'line1'`
`.'line2'`
`.'line3'`

Comment: I see that last symbol of last line is really deleted. I fixed regex function. Check again pls. Now it should work. Here is demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9ea549dccad3fd066df73aca9978041ad5f7f81

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I tested your code , it works but need improvment .
if we have an empty line between the lines of code of the input, we need output to be an empty line too . but the introduced code produce `.'` to the first and `'` on another line .

sample input :
`line1`  `line3`
required output :
`.'line1'`

`.'line3'`

but the produce output is :
`.'line1'`
`.'`
`'`
`.'line3'`

Comment: fixed. Need to just change from plus sign `+` to `*` which mean at least one symbol found.

Comment: Thanks for the improvments .
but required output : 
`.'line1'`
`empty line` 
`.'line3'`
but the produced output is : 
`.'line1'`
`.''` 
`.'line3'`

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept the answer then, thank you.

Comment: In The Name Of GOD, hello, Can you please help me in this topic too . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218247/please-convert-2-regular-expressions-codes-s-s-and-1-from-notepad-fi